# How to retrieve files in App_Data folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

So a lot of people are saying that don't store files in database but save them (actual files) in server folder and save the file's path to database.

Problem is files can be access directly through urls. For example if I put a iamge to folder named: img then people can easily access it via, for example this url: http://domain.com/img/photo.jpg

My web application will have a lot image and documents that should only be available after you logged in.

I put them in App_Data folder because it is a secured folder to avoid them being access by unauthorized users, but guess what I can not retrieve them in my code...

For example: I can't get a profile picture of user and display it to the page ...

SQL Database:
[image]

.aspx page:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgProfile" runat="server" Width="150" Height="150" ToolTip="Profile Picture" />
```

c# code behind in Page_Load event:

```
   //Get name and path and save to ProfilePicture object
   //.....
   imgProfile.ImageUrl = ProfilePicture.path + ProfilePicture.name;
```

The browser (Chrome) said:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/users/..../App_Data/User/userPicture/1/photo.JPG localhost:55700/Modules/User/Account/ProfilePicture.aspx:196
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

So what is the best solution here, look like I have to put them in database...

Comment: That makes sense, doesn't it? You didn't want it to be accessible through an URL, and forwarding an URL is all that `<asp:Image>` does.

Comment: And anyway you shouldn't use Server.MapPath here.

Comment: Public cannot access files stored inside **App_Data**. If images are stored inside **App_Data**, you need to access them via **Handler**. **FYI**: Images are ok to store in database, although large files are not recommended.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Right I remove the Server.MapPath, but if I dont put the picture fle in App_Data folder, people can access it anywhere anytime once they known the URL (they can get it simply by inspect the picture). I only want logged users can access it.

Comment: When `<asp:Image>` can show it, people can access it. So you need another control, see @Sam's answer.

Answer (score 0):

AppData is a user dependent system directory.
it can be found under `c:\users\[username]\appdata`
you should be careful about which appdata forlder IIS is accessing, since it's probably running under a different user than your desktop
Now, making the appdata content available on your webapp is a very bad practice.
the correct way to do it, and if you insist on hiding the images, you must create a handler (.ashx) which will read the image file and return back.

Comment: Please provide example of a handler (how it get file from a folder so I can put files in other folder rather than the app_data), this concept is completely new to me.

Comment: Sam doesn't have to provide an example, plenty are already on the site. Google for it.